# Are there Pan-Indian Hindu festivals dedicated to Vishnu or Narayana?

Tags: vishnu, festivals

Janmashtami and Ram Navami are dedicated to Vishnu's avataras and are Pan-Indian. But are there any such festivals dedicated to Vishnu or Narayna?

Comment: By Pan Indian, you mean the festivals practiced by all Indians or religious practice participated in by many or all North American Indian peoples. These two are the definitions I found by googling. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The main things we commemorate in regard to Vishnu's deeds are deeds where he did something on Earth, and he generally does such deeds by descending on Earth in the form of an incarnation.  So most holidays associated with Vishnu are connected to incarnations.  But for instance there is Vaikuntha Ekadashi.